# Можно ли определить местоположение телефона по мобильным данным без присутствия SIM карты?

Tags: android, сеть, позиционирование

Мы знаем что без SIM карты подключение сотовой сети (GSM) невозможен. НО в WI FI позиционировании даже если устройство не подключена к точкам доступа Wi-Fi и мы не знаем пароль наше  устройство (в данном случае мобильный телефон ) все равно может получать RSSI и другие параметры, необходимые для выполнения позиционирования, от всех точек доступов  в диапазоне.
Вопрос:
Возможна ли  подобным образом позиционирование по сотовым вышкам если на телефоне нет SIM карты (ведь прием и передача данных производится не по SIM карте правда ? в телефоне есть необходимая аппаратура для приема-передачи сигналов. а SIM карта для идентификации)

Comment: А БС как-то передаёт свои точные координаты? А если передаёт, мы можем им доверять? Проблема, насколько я понимаю, в основном в том, что мы не знаем координаты тех БС, которые слышим. Гугль, например, их знает, поэтому телефон может выполнять быстрое примерное позиционирование и без GPS при наличии связи с тем гуглом.

Comment: именно это я и спрашиваю. как знаем точки доступа wi fi  передают свой SSID даже если мы не подключены им. А передают ли базовые станции свои координаты? и может ли наше устройство слышать и понимать эти эти координаты ( и вообще любые другие сигналы от Б.С.?) БЕЗ SIM КАРТЫ ?

Comment: как бы расстояние до вайфай точки доступа невелико, а вот БС от тебя в зависимости от района может быть как 300 метров так и 2-3 км, тот же гугл тебе не выдаст нормальные координаты через location-провайдера network, если у тебя вайфай-адаптер выключен или рядом нет известных WIFI-сетей.

Comment: И причем тут андройд? https://3dnews.ru/655897

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, знаем знаем мы координаты всех БС https://radiocells.org/downloads  https://www.opencellid.org/